# Print to PDF from Any Printer Driver

Tags: drivers, pdf, printing, printer

I have been trying to figure out this one for a while but alas i can't.

I wanna print PDF from any printer driver, lets say, an EPSON TM-T20II, I have PDFCreator installed, and tried using its port, but it crashes.

The origin of this request is, i have to test multiple printers and print options for my clients, and well, i dont always carry every single printer with me, so i wanna try with PDF. But i can't configure the proper sizes on PDFCreator.

So, any suggestions or solutions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Printer driver output as a source**

Printer drivers take output requirements from an application (what needs to appear on the page and where), and translate that to commands used by the printer to approximate it with the printer's hardware.  If you want to test a specific printer without the printer, you need special software that translates the raw printer commands, typically captured from the print spooler, to something usable, like PDF.

Note that since the printer commands produce only an approximation of the application output specs, you can't perfectly recreate the output specs by translating the printer commands.  When you translate the output into another form, you get degradation reflecting the limitations of the hardware for which the commands were intended.

So translating printer commands to PDF and then viewing that PDF will look different from PDF output produced directly from the application.  But it won't be a perfect representation of the printed output either.  Applying a dot of ink or toner (or a spot of heat to thermal paper), doesn't have the same dot size or characteristics as a pixel in a PDF.

**What is required**

You can't use a PDF printer driver to translate the output of another printer driver.  And PDF utilities, like PDFCreator, are designed to work with an application or a common file format, not printer commands.

Before the advent of PDF (going back to the days of Windows 98), there was a need for this kind of thing, and there were a few applications developed that did that, primarily for PCL (Printer Command Language, developed by HP, and the backbone of their printer protocols).  It turns out that some of this stuff is still around, like [VeryPDF PCL Converter](http://www.verypdf.com/app/pcl-converter/index.html), which isn't cheap, and I can't vouch for how well it would translate printer-specific output.

If you hunt the Internet, you may still find similar software that might work with some of the major printer brands, at least to the extent you're testing simple printing requirements and not invoking any special printer features.  That said, I would be surprised if this kind of software is available for something like a thermal receipt printer, as in the question.

**Thoughts on solutions**

There isn't a generic way to do this.  If you want to verify output for specific printers, you either need the printers, or what would likely be custom software to translate or validate the output.  Keep in mind that even translating printer commands to PDF isn't 100% foolproof.  You can have commands that are valid, and will produce a correct-looking PDF, but the output may not meet the constraints of a specific printer, so won't work in real life.

Buying printers would be faster and cheaper than creating custom software.  But if this is for clients, you could ask them to lend you a printer for testing, or go there and test on their printers (or ask them to test for you).

If you are just interested in the output layout (appearance on the page), and don't need to test a specific printer's ability to render it, and if you are using common software to create the output, I would think you could use almost any PDF printer driver, or pick from the readily available PDF utilities.

Comment: Thanks. That was enlightening, I didn't think it was gonna be simple, but now I understand a bit better how printers work. I'm gonna mark this as solved. Thank you.